# Does Aloe Vera bloom?

Tags: plant-care, aloe

I noticed today a kind of an 'offspring' on my Aloe Vera plant.
This big plant produces many offsprings all the time but they always come from the roots and look different from this one. This is the first time I am seeing something like it. Can anyone tell what is it and if this means the plant is in some kind of stress. 
I water the plant once in two weeks and it gets a lot of light.
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks like an Aloe, but are you sure it's Aloe vera specifically? It looks more like our huge, fast-growing Aloe. Aloe vera tends to have less blue in its green, tenda to be smaller, and has speckles on its leaves. But yeah, I'm pretty sure most or all Aloe flower given the right conditions. We have a plant that flowered like that in the recent past. Never seen Aloe vera specifically flower, though.

Comment: It is green though but I didn't clean it. I will add a new photo so you can see it's color. As for the speckles they dissapeared as the plant got bigger, the offsprings always have speckles. Also it doesn't grow fast at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're having a flower! Aloe do indeed flower. It depends on plant maturity, treatment, sunshine, etc.

It sounds like you're treating it well.

It's not an Aloe vera (barbadensis), it's some other species. I'm more of an aloe generalist, so I won't guess at the correct ID.

Comment: Just be warned that on some species, the flower spike is several times taller than the rest of the plant. It may take several months before the flower finally opens, but start thinking now about how to support it before the whole pot topples over!