# Are these Aloe Vera's seeds?

Tags: houseplants, seeds, propagation, aloe

I posted a question a few weeks ago asking if my aloe was going to bloom. [Does Aloe Vera bloom?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/49908/does-aloe-vera-bloom)

I have now flowers that look like they have seeds in them but I'm not sure about it.
So I was wondering if anyone can tell are they seeds and if they are how should I plant them

[image][image][image]

Comment: Those aren't seeds, they are spent flowers. Aloe will make a fruit if it was successfully pollinated. Many Aloe are self sterile, so unless there is another compatible plant in bloom and a means to get pollen from one to the other, you're unlikely to get seeds, especially indoors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The seeds may or may not  be viable, but you need to wait for each flower to fade and dry out a bit before collecting the seed. More  information on how to grow from seed here https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/aloe-vera/growing-aloe-seeds.htm