# Are these aloe vera seeds viable?

Tags: seeds, aloe

I have a single aloe vera plant outdoors. It started growing what appears to be flowers. The pods near the bottom become slightly drier and eventually fall to the ground. The pods never open up like normal flowers.

I’ve been saving the ones that have fallen to the ground. They are still slightly moist. I peeled open on of these pods. There’s a seed-like green thing inside them with a long stamen (maybe) still protruding out of it. My question is this a fully developed seed and will I get a new plant after sowing it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer here  may be helpful [Are these Aloe Vera's seeds?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/51579/are-these-aloe-veras-seeds), but as to their viability, you will only know if you sow them and they do (or don't) germnate and grow.

Comment: @TimNevins well at least its a very recent deja vu - I didn't have to look far for my linked answer!

Comment: When you said “wait for them to dry out and fade” is that done by them naturally falling to the ground? They are indeed drier and more faded, but not to the point where the wrapping is crispy yet. Do they need additional curing time or can I just sow them right now? Also do I sow them with the stamen attached?

Comment: the link provided in  the previous answer that's linked to yours in the answer tells you when and how to harvest the seeds - the  pods need to be dry and crispy...